# Как удалить всё из объекта (ассоциативного массива) с сохранением ссылки на оригинальный объект

Tags: javascript, объекты

Как очистить объект с данными, например:

```
var map = {
  '12': {id: 12},
  '36': {id: 37}
};
```

Простая замена `map = {};` не подходит, поскольку неизвестно, кто ещё владеет ссылками на этот объект.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы быть уверенным, что вы случайно не замените ссылку на такой объект, лучше всего использовать константные ссылки:

```
const map = {
  '12': {id: 12},
  '36': {id: 37}
};
```

Нативные способы такой очистки мне пока неизвестны.

Так или иначе придётся пройтись по всем ключам объекта и удалить их инструкцией `delete`. Варианты:

```
Object.keys(map).forEach(key => (delete map[key]));      // перечисляемые свойства
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(map).forEach(key => (delete map[key])); // все свойства

for (const key of Object.keys(map)) delete map[key];
for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(map)) delete map[key];

// без свойств прототипов, delete map[key] не сможет их удалить =)
for (const key in map) if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) delete map[key];
```

Comment: не всегда delete может сработать, например, если у свойства установлено `configurable:false` - delete просто вернет `false` и свойство никуда не денется

Comment: @Grundy, можно сделать многое, тот же freeze, но вопрос был не об этом. Я просто сдампил оффлайн вопрос, который мне задали)

Comment: `freeze` как раз и проставляет `configurable:false` для всех свойств :-)